# Powershell script for returning samaccountname to static variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

I'm trying to create a script for remote deletion of local profiles across the network.

I am using delprof2 as the program and I have got it set to the computers network name but when trying to specify the username to look for and delete, the script returns the full DistinguishedName including the OU and Dc etc.  All I need it to return is the SamAccountName contents without the CN= infront.

Can anyone help?

I've tried a `-filter` instead of `-ldapfilter`.
I've changed the samaccount name in the brackets to `$name.samaccountname=` and even `CN=`.

```
function CheckUser{
    $user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$user)"
    If ($user  -eq $Null) 
    {"User does not exist in AD";GetUserName}
    Else {GetMenu}
```

The required outcome is for the `$user` variable to hold the SamAccountName data only.

Comment: what info do you have already? your code says you already have the SamAccountName ... then you say you want the SamAccountName ... i am very, very, very confused! [*blush*]

Comment: Try: `$Samaccountname = $User | Select -Expand samaccountname` or just: `$Samaccountname = $User.samaccountname`

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADUser` returns the property `SamAccountName` by default, aswell as `DistinguishedName`, `Enabled`, `GivenName`, `Name`, `ObjectClass`, `ObjectGUID`, `SID`, `Surname` and `UserPrincipalName`.

The [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#required-parameters) cmdlet can take the following entries for its `-Identity` parameter:

- DistinguishedName
- GUID
- SID
- SamAccountName

and if like your question suggests you already have the DistinghuishedName or SamAccountName to check on, you can simply use that for the Identity parameter and not use the Filter at all.

Something like this should work:

```
function CheckUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$UserToCheck  # can be DistinghuishedName, GUID, SID or SamAccountName
    )
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $UserToCheck
    if (!$user) { 
        "User does not exist in AD" 
    }
    else {
        # return the SamAccountName of the user
        return $user.SamAccountName
    }
}
```

Use this like

```
$samaccountname = CheckUser -UserToCheck 'the property you have, like the DistinghuishedName'
```

If you have some other property of the user you need to use, like email address, then you DO need to use the filter (or LDAPFilter) to search for the user.
Something like

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$UserToCheck'"
```

or

```
$user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(mail=$UserToCheck)"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones help

after trying what everyone suggested I changed the script around in its original form and in context this now works

```
function CheckUser{
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") = $user
    If ($user  -eq $Null) 
    {"User does not exist in AD";GetUserName}
    Else {GetMenu}
}
```

as you can see this is now setting the samaccountname as the $user

I put a test in using a menu function 
 4 {#Show Stored Username
    Read-host $user
    CheckUser
    }

and the output is the correct username

This now passes the correct variable to DelProf2.exe for remote profile deletion.

Comment: So you just swapped `$user = ..` to `.. =$user`.. That is totally wrong I'm afraid. Did you really test this?